# How to pass this three inputs (lineEdit, startDate, endDate) to my function (graphdata)

Tags: python, qt, highcharts, pyqt4

I am new to QT. I got this error

> K = l.toFloat(); AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute
>   'toFloat'

I want to input `lineEdit`, `startDate`, `endDate` to be proceeded by `graphdata function` using proceed button `pushButton`.

The lineEdit should be `float` and date should be in this format `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.
This is the UI Code:

```
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)        

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(333, 241)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.dateEdit = QtGui.QDateEdit(Form)
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dateEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dateEdit)
        self.dateEdit_2 = QtGui.QDateEdit(Form)
        self.dateEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dateEdit_2"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dateEdit_2)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "XMIP Chart", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Chart Setting", None))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Form", "Input Block Size", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Proceed", None))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.graphdata)"""I called the graphdata here"""

    def graphdata(self):
        l = self.lineEdit.text()
        K = l.toFloat();
        mulai = (self.dateEdit.date)
        akhir = (self.dateEdit_2.date)
        start= mulai.toString();
        end = akhir.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The class definition is just for defining the class and what kind of functions it has. To actually use the class you need to instantiate it somewhere else and call the defined functions.

So in your case: Outside of your class you should create an instance of your class `UI_Form` and call the `graphdata()`function on it, like this:

```
my_form = UI_Form()
my_form.graphdata()
```

Read up on the word "instantiation" to learn more.

The `self` argument is required in each class function in python. By calling `my_form.graphdata()` `my_form` is passed as `self`argument behind the scenes. So remember: You only add `self` as argument in the function definition but never pass it as argument when using the function!

Comment: when I edit as your suggestion, get error _TypeError: 'QLineEdit' object is not callable_ the I changed the code to 'def graphdata(self):
        l = self.lineEdit.text()
        K = float(l)
        K = float(self.lineEdit())
        start = (self.dateEdit.date.toString("yyyy-mm-dd"))
        end = (self.dateEdit_2.date.toString("yyyy-mm-dd"))', get me error _ValueError: could not convert string to float: Input Block Size_

Comment: Yes, now you receive the errors of the wrong code in your successfully called function. `self.lineEdit.text()` returns the content of the widget which you can then convert to float. Please read the documentation on that.

Comment: `l = self.lineEdit.text()
        K = float(l)` I tried that to convert to float, get error _ValueError: could not convert string to float_

Comment: I read several times as you suggest _http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html_ and could not find, might be lineedit string could not be converted

Comment: If you look at what QLineEdit's `text()` returns, you will see that it is a QString. Now if you look at the QString documentation, you will see, how you can convert it to float: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstring.html#toFloat

Comment: I change code to `l = self.lineEdit.text()  K = l.toFloat();` get error _'unicode' object has no attribute 'toFloat'_

Comment: Apologies, I was tired yesterday. The way you tried to convert to float is already correct, since you are using python. Your error `ValueError: could not convert string to float` indicates that your line edit contained text that was not a number so that it cannot be converted to a float.

Comment: I already input 0.001. it gave me headache, only to input this but could not make it in two days. I suspect this QDate things will also add problem later :(. thank you for your help